# (JavaScript) Compare Timestamps daily (over span of 2 years)

Tags: javascript, date, time, timestamp, intervals

I have this survey application that stores when my respondents have taken my survey using a JavaScript timestamp (ex 2015-06-18T10:35:26.980Z)

What I need to find out is how many respondents have taken the survey daily. I'm not very sure how to compare the dates daily starting from, for example, 2 years ago. Any pointers how I should proceed?

So far I have an array of the date/time when my respondents took the survey. Many thanks!

Edit: 
Code so far.

```
var dateCounter = {};

  timeStart.forEach(function(date) {
  var key = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
  dateCounter[key] = dateCounter[key] || 0;
  dateCounter[key] += 1;
  });
```

console.log(dateCounter);

Comment: Loop through the array, keep count of each day using an object with keys that are the date part of the timestamp

Comment: There is no "JavaScript timestamp". The string "2015-06-18T10:35:26.980Z" might be described as an ISO 8601 long format string though. One benefit of the ISO format is that it sorts nicely as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty snippet

```
var dateCounter ={};
dateArray.forEach(function(date) {
    var key = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    dateCounter[key] = dateCounter[key] || 0;
    dateCounter[key] += 1;
});
```

At the end of this, dateCounter should have a bunch of totals for each date

Comment: thanks Jaramanda. I am testing it out right now, but for some reason, I'm getting an error that 'date.toISOString()' is not a function. Here's my code in the edit above.

Comment: not sure what that code snippet is supposed to be doing, but there's no array of date/time as you mentioned in your question ... you're trying to process a single time value as if it's an array if dates, hence why you get an error

Comment: sorry about that. timeStart is the array of my date/time. What exactly is dateArray in your code?

Comment: And where should I put my array timeStart?

Comment: it's an array of dates that you mentioned in your question, I gave it a name to show some code, I could've called it "your_array_of_dates" :p - where should you "put" it? No idea, you said that so far you have an array of date/times, I assumed that meant you had a variable of type Array with data in it

Comment: Yes, in my code, my array of dates is timeStart, which I've replaced dateArray with.

Comment: I guess what I'm confused with now is what is date?

Comment: Sorry for the all the questions.

Comment: date (rather than Date) is just a function parameter name - in your function you've called it beginning - you could also call it fred or martha, it doesn't matter, as long as you use it correctly